# How do I load one style sheet for mobile devices and one for desktops?

Tags: css

The reason I'd like to do this is we have dropdown menues on our "desktop version" that i'd like to hide (because they don't work very well on a touch screen device) and show a simplified menu with just the "basic" links.

I can't make Media Queries work when detecting a device because the resolution is too high on some of them (Samsung Galaxy S3 for example).

Is there a Javascript or something I can use? Something like (I don't know Javascript so this is just the idea):

```
if mobileDevice then load mobile.css
else
load desktop.css
```

Just the basic idea :-)

Comment: Can't you just use the user agent ?

Comment: Can that be done for devices and not just for browsers? For example I would like Safari on a desktop computer to load desktop.css and Safari on an iPhone to load mobile.css.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the user agent of safari on a computer is different than a safari on an iPhone.

Answer (score 8):

Use `media` attribute specific to the screens like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" />
```

And for handheld devices you can use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 400px)' href='stylesheet.css' />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="handheld" />
```

Or use @media queries to target specific screen resolutions if you want than you can simply have 1 stylesheet but you can define styles for different screens like this

```
@media screen {
      /* Styles for screen goes here */
}

@media print {
      /* Styles for print goes here */
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* Styles for specific screen resolutions */
}
```

Comment: The problem is that a Samsung Galaxy S3 for example has a resolution of 1280X720 which would load the "desktop.css"

Comment: @user1823082 ya so why you are loading desktop.css? just make another stylesheet for this specific screen resolution

Comment: Well, there are computers that have the same screen resolution as the S3 and I don't want them to load the mobile.css.

Comment: `screen`: Used for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of code "snippets" and I wonder if they could be combined into a working script?

```
if(Browser.Platform.name == 'android' || Browser.Platform.name == 'ios') window.location = dir+mobileFolder+"/index.html"+page;

//*** Could the above be combined with the below in some way? ***

function loadcssfile(filename, filetype){
// if (filetype=="css"){
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
//}

loadcssfile("stylesheet.css", "css")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="handheld"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: To my knowledge, most major mobile devices don't have support for media="handheld" strangely enough. Otherwise that would have been a nice solution.