# Applying bootstrap only on mobile

Tags: refactoring, responsive

I have a legacy website to work on and this does not support any mobile browsers. This web has a gigantic amount of css files and the look & feel of the web is not to be modified. Bootstrap will be used to make the web responsive for mobile users.

The problem is, I'd like the web to apply bootstrap only for mobile browsers. Let's say the following html code is from the legacy web and it's not responsive.

```html
<div id="header">
    <div><img src="view/image/logo.png"/></div>
    <div><img src="view/image/lock.png"</div>
</div>
```

If you add row and column classes...

```html
<div id="header" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="view/image/logo.png"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="view/image/lock.png"/></div>
</div>
```

Now, it is responsive for mobile browsers but .row also changes the margin & padding of #header for PC browsers which is not meant to be. So, I came up with two solutions for this problem.

1. Import bootstrap under @media.

   - I think this is impossible because bootstrap already has its own @media queries. Also, having @media under @media is a total nonsense.
2. Detect whether the current browser is on PC or mobile before loading bootstrap theme.

   - This is a better solution than #1 and I can't come up with any drawbacks from it.

Are there any alternative approaches to tackle this problem?

Comment: Ah, there's one drawback for solution #2. It cannot be responsive on PC since the codes detects whether the current browsser is on mobile...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375307/how-do-i-load-one-style-sheet-for-mobile-devices-and-one-for-desktops might be helpful